# Is it possible to take raw-images with Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, camera

Is it possible to take raw-images with Ubuntu phone (BQ-model or other upcoming smartphones)?

Answer (score 0):

No, currently it is not possible. Here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1497872) against the camera-app. As there are multiple more important features missing in the camera-app (see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1370669) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/camera-app/+bug/1370671)) I wouldn’t expect RAW images anytime soon.